# How to retain specific part of an xml with same element names using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an input xml file and a XSLT script.
My input xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Lib>
  <book>---</book>            <!-- from here -->
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
  ...
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
  <regn settr="---">
    <pointall>
      <author settr="---">
        <point>
          <entry settr="---" value="---" />
        </point>
      </author> 
      <author settr="---">
        <point>
          <entry settr="---" value="---" />
        </point>
      </author>
       ...
       ...
    </pointall>    
  </regn>              <!-- to here -->
  <regn settr="register">
    <card>
      <author settr="register">
        <note>
          <book>---</book>
          <regn settr="---" value="---" />
          <regn settr="---">
            <pointall>
              <author settr="---">
                <point>
                  <some settr="---" value="" />
                </point>
              </author>
            </pointall>
          </regn>
        </note>
      </author>
    </card>
  </regn>
  <regn settr="write">
    <card>
      <author settr="write">
        <note>
          <book>---</book>
          <regn settr="---" value="---" />
            <pointall />
        </note>
      </author>
    </card>
  </regn>
  ...
  ...
  <regn settr="...">
    <card>
      <author settr="...">
        ...
      </author>
    </card>
  </regn>
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
</Lib>
```

I am applying XSLT template transformation for the `regn` elements starting from   `<regn settr="register">` onwards and then going down. My XSLT looks something like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Lib">
    <xsl:copy>
     <regn settr="Librarian">
      <xsl:copy-of select="regn/card"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which applies and transforms my input xml to the below output xml :

```
<Lib>
  <regn settr="Librarian">
    <card>
      <author settr="register">
        <note>
          <book>---</book>
          <regn settr="---" value="---" />
          <regn settr="---">
            <pointall>
              <author settr="---">
                <point>
                  <some settr="---" value="" />
                </point>
              </author>
            </pointall>
          </regn>
        </note>
      </author>
    </card>
    <card>
      <author settr="write">
        <note>
          <book>---</book>
          <regn settr="---" value="---" />
            <pointall />
        </note>
      </author>
    </card>
  ...
  ...
    <card>
      <author settr="...">
        ...
      </author>
    </card>
  </regn>
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
</Lib>
```

i.e. it transforms `<regn settr="register">`, `<regn settr="write">`, and the following future `<regn settr="...">` elements all as one element which is `<regn settr="Librarian">`.

But I don't get the content which are after `<Lib>` and before `<regn settr="register">`, i.e. the content which I have mentioned in comment line starting "from here" to "to here". I need to retain those content as well. Also **register**, **write**, and any other values that may come after that in the future in regn settr element, are dummy values which maynot be fixed for every input file.

Expected Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Lib>
<book>---</book>            <!-- from here -->
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
  ...
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
  <regn settr="---">
    <pointall>
      <author settr="---">
        <point>
          <entry settr="---" value="---" />
        </point>
      </author> 
      <author settr="---">
        <point>
          <entry settr="---" value="---" />
        </point>
      </author>
       ...
       ...
    </pointall>    
  </regn>              <!-- to here -->
  <regn settr="Librarian">
    <card>
      <author settr="register">
        <note>
          <book>---</book>
          <regn settr="---" value="---" />
          <regn settr="---">
            <pointall>
              <author settr="---">
                <point>
                  <some settr="---" value="" />
                </point>
              </author>
            </pointall>
          </regn>
        </note>
      </author>
    </card>
    <card>
      <author settr="write">
        <note>
          <book>---</book>
          <regn settr="---" value="---" />
            <pointall />
        </note>
      </author>
    </card>
  ...
  ...
    <card>
      <author settr="...">
        ...
      </author>
    </card>
  </regn>
  <regn settr="---" value="---" />
</Lib>
```

I tried something like this for it but I am not getting desired output from it:

```
  <xsl:template match="/Lib">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <regn settr="Librarian">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="regn/card"/>
        </regn>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out here? Thankyou!

Comment: Your intent says `<!-- apply template logic -->` but your code `<xsl:copy-of select="regn/card"/>` makes a deep copy of `regn/card`. If you want to apply templates you need `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of`. On the other hand, you haven't written any templates other than using the identity transformation, so it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Martin..I was trying to generalize the xslt and post it but I may have compressed it a bit too much, my bad. I have edited the xslt and added the original part of `<!-- apply template logic -->`. But my problem remains the same, I am not able to retain the content mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Martin..I tried the `xsl:apply-templates` logic which is why I have edited my sample xslt. But I am still not able to get up from this point, I am not able to apply the templates AND retain the mentioned content above it at the same time. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might simply want the identity transformation plus one change of the attribute e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="regn/@settr[. = 'register']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">Librarian</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```